# Scheme - How can eval recognize a variable?

Tags: variables, scheme, eval

So for instance if i define a function:

```
(define (^ x y) (expt x y))
```

then eval can recognize (^ 3 3) and evaluate it , but i need it to evaluate variables read in from input (that aren't constant, meaning they can be changed later on per say if the same variable was read in with a different value).

Is there a way eval can recognize variables?

Comment: I feel this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In R5RS you have a second argument to `eval`. An optional procedure is `interaction-environment`, which returns the current environment, but for an implementation that has it it will do what you want. You still won't get lexical variables though. In [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-17.html#node_idx_1266) it's not doable since you can only import from libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The exact conventions of how to use `eval` differ from implementation to implementation - so the bedst advice is to lookup `eval` in the documentation of you Scheme implementation.

That said the official documentation on `eval` in R5RS says:

```
procedure:  (eval expression environment-specifier) 

Evaluates expression in the specified environment and returns its value. 
Expression must be a valid Scheme expression represented as data, 
and environment-specifier must be a value returned by one of the three
procedures described below. Implementations may extend eval to allow non-
expression programs (definitions) as the first argument and to allow other
values as environments, with the restriction that eval is not allowed to 
create new bindings in the environments associated with null-environment or 
scheme-report-environment.


(eval '(* 7 3) (scheme-report-environment 5))
                                                           ===>  21

(let ((f (eval '(lambda (f x) (f x x))
               (null-environment 5))))
  (f + 10))
                                                           ===>  20
```